# ViewSonic VX2453 series monitor looks pink on RGB mode

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, rgb, yuv

I am using two ViewSonic VX2453s for my PC. One of them is fine on RGB (which I am looking to have both monitors be on), but the other is pink when seitched from YUV to RGB mode. It resets back to YUV mode after the screen is turned off. Does this have to do with my graphics card? I am using a GeForce GTX 970 for my main (RGB) monitor and a Radeon HD 5450 for my second (YUV, pink on RGB) monitor. If that is the case, I do not know why YUV mode works fine but RGB mode doesn't.

[image: The Monitor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a different display adapter. Some display adapters may only support YUV mode on certain monitors. My GTX 970 can run both in RGB mode, but my Radeon HD 5450 could only display in YUV mode.